# Differentiate Common Http Errors in URL.openStream()

Tags: java, android, sockets, url, inputstream

I am quite stuck as **I have to differentiate common HTTP Errors occurred during Url.openStream()**. Main purpose is to identify following HTTP Get request errors:

1. 400 (bad request)
2. 401 (unauthorized)
3. 403 (forbidden)
4. 404 (not found)
5. 500 (internal server error)

**Till now i could identify only 404 by catching FileNotFoundException. This is my code snippet:**

```
try {
    file.createNewFile();
    URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.connect();

    // download the file
    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

    // store the file
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
    int count;
    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        output.write(data, 0, count);
        Log.e(TAG, "Writing");
    }

    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
    result = HTTP_SUCCESS;
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Exception found FileNotFoundException=" + fnfe);
    Log.e(TAG, "FILE NOT FOUND");
    result = HTTP_FILE_NOT_FOUND;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Exception found=" + e);
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    Log.e(TAG, "NETWORK_FAILURE");
    result = NETWORK_FAILURE;
}
```

**It may be a small problem but I am totally clueless.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use HTTP cast your connection to `HttpUrlConnection` and before open stream check response status code using `connection.getResponseCode()`:

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
/* ... */
final int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
switch (responseCode) {
  case 404:
  /* ... */
  case 200: {
    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

And do not forget close connection in `finally` block.

Comment: *If you use HTTP* -- HTTP versus HTTPS?  Or just versus FTP or another thing entirely?